# Is there a good way to document attributes with `python-attrs`?

Tags: python, python-attrs

I'm used to documenting my `__init__()` function with a docstring, but I would like to take advantage of the benefits of the [attrs](https://www.attrs.org) package.  The docstring is useful in IPython or a Jupyter notebook, so I can see what the parameters mean.  Is there a good way to do this?  In this example code:

```python
@atrr.s
class Coordinates(object):
    """ A set of coordinates
    """
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()

"""
In [1]: Coordinates?
Init signature: Coordinates(x, y) -> None
Docstring:     
A set of coordinates
    
Init docstring: Method generated by attrs for class Coordinates.
Type:           type
Subclasses:
"""
```

how can I describe the `x` and `y` variables to the user?  For example, how can I specify that these are in degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the documentation of attributes and (more importantly) `__init__` arguments happens in the **class docstring**, therefore the presence of `attrs` is not important in this case:

```
@attr.define
class Coordinates:
    """
    A set of coordinates.

    :param int x: Foo in degrees.
    :param int y: Bar in degrees.
    """
    x: int
    y: int
```

For more information check out RTD's [docs on writing docstrings](https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docstrings.html#an-example-class-with-docstrings).

If you don't like this format, another common one is called Napoleon and comes from Google: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html

Comment: I was thinking more of the [numpy style](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#documenting-classes]), but you make a good point. They say `__init__` is documented in the Class docstring.

Comment: I have seen this discussed elsewhere, but I still reckon it would be nice to be able to put the doc string immediately below the attribute. That way if you add/remove attributes you don't need to remember to also edit the classes docstring. Couldn't `attrs.define` detect the presence of the doc strings and add them to the auto docs?

Comment: There is a very old ticket open about this that enumerates some of the problems and possible solutions: https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/357 Docstrings won't work tho, because they often aren't even a thing. Try experimenting with adding docstrings to attributes or even annotated fields and retrieving them – it's impossible.